# Segmenting connected characters in an image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ocr, image-segmentation

My aim is to correctly segment the characters in an image

My image looks like this: [image]

How can I correctly segment the connected B and W? Also my code seems to find that 750 are all connected as well. How do I segment them?

Which transformation must I apply? I tried erode but it did not help? How is the kernel size selected for such an image? How should I remove the noise on 5 and M?

What changes should I make to my code to correctly segment and isolate every character? 
Code:

```
img = cv2.imread('C:\\xx\\testimages\\X\\plate4.jpg', 0)
cv2.threshold(img,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU,img)
image, contours, hier = cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
contours = sorted(contours, key=lambda ctr: cv2.boundingRect(ctr)[0])
d=0
for ctr in contours:
    # Get bounding box
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(ctr)
    # Getting ROI
        if w>20 and h>20 and w<60:       #Boundary conditions to isolate a character
            print(x, y, w, h)
            roi = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]
            #roi=cv2.resize(roi,(20,35))
            #kernel = np.ones((3,3), np.uint8)
            #roi = cv2.morphologyEx(roi, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
            #roi = cv2.erode(roi, kernel, iterations=1)
            # kernel_1=np.ones((1,1),np.uint8)
            # roi=cv2.dilate(roi,kernel,iterations=1)
            cv2.imshow('character: %d' % d, roi)
            cv2.imwrite('C:\\xx\\ValidationSet\\character_%d.png'%d, roi)
            cv2.waitKey(0)
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            d+=1
```

Comment: Eroding the image before contouring (not after) should help.

Comment: @jedwards On what basis is the kernel size selected for erosion?

Comment: That'll depend a lot on the resolution of the images and the size (pixel-wise) of the characters within.  You could either play around manually and try to figure out a reasonable kernel size, or perhaps detect contours that are "too wide" relative to the other detected contours and adaptively erode in that case.  Unfortunately, there's no one-size-fits all answer in this case.

Comment: @jedwards I eroded the image before contouring. It helped me separate the '7' from 50 but does not work with BW and 50. Increasing the kernel size then just worsens the other character segmentations as they become unrecognizable. What should I do?

Comment: Rather than a larger kernel, you might try more iterations of a smaller one.  But I agree, don't go "too large".

Comment: @jedwards Ah yes, I tried doing that. A 2,2 kernel with 4 iterations but it still does not seem to break the connection. IS there any other transformation which I could apply? I also tried to create a topological skeleton to see if i could separate the letters but it does not work? And this is just one case. Trying to many operations for just this one image could lead to loss of generality for an overall set

Comment: @xmacz what kernel are you using?

Answer (score 0):

As people recommended in the comments already, the best options is to use morphological transforms, like erosion and opening.
Regarding the kernel size, you can make it a function of the width of your contours, or just iterate multiple times applying a small kernel of size (3, 3) or (5,5). I personally found this [tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/db/df6/tutorial_erosion_dilatation.html) (in C++, but the concept is the same) simple and useful.
Regarding noise removal from the "5" and "M", you can't do that in a generic way that will generalize to all possible types of noise. If you have more information on the statistics of the errors or some more information (e.g. the "noise" always manifest in the form of white pixels on top of the current character) it is easier and doable, of course.